# File.WriteAllBytes or FileStream.Write

Tags: c#, stream, filestream

What's the difference between File.WriteAllBytes and FileStream.Write/WriteBytes? I have a bitmap object that and I want to create a new bmp/jpg/png on disk. I think I read somewhere that WriteAllBytes uses FileStream.Write underneath?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`WriteAllBytes` is just a convinience method, that wraps the underlying `Stream` operations. (Create a file, write to stream, close stream, etc). Use it if it fits your needs. If you need more control on the underlying operations, fallback to using a `Stream`or similar.

It is all about using the right abstraction for the task.

Comment: FYI:
@driis is correct, below is the actual code used by the .Net framework (master branch)

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L462

Answer (score 3):

Use WriteAllBytes to just save all the bytes, use Write if you need to watch the progress.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the wrong track with this.  Saving a bitmap object requires Image.Save().  That's a method that knows how to use an image encoder to convert a bitmap into the bytes that another program (or yours) can load back.  There are several image encoders, you can select the one you want with the Save() overload that lets you pick the ImageFormat.  The BMP format is the native Windows format, it is uncompressed.  The PNG format is nice, it is a compressed lossless format.  The JPEG format is a compressed lossy format, good for photos.  File size is big to small in order.

Answer (score 1):

You should use WriteAllBytes if you want to save a bitmap.